# Unary operator '--' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'

Tags: iphone, swift

```
@IBAction func blueBtnAct(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    score++  //error bcause Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'
    blueLbl.text = "\(score)"
    GrenLbl.text = "\(score)"
    testScore()
}
@IBAction func GrenBtnAct(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    score--  //error bcause Unary operator '--' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue Int'
    blueLbl.text = "\(score)"
    GrenLbl.text = "\(score)"
    testScore()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use use `score = score + 1` instead of `score++`

Comment: The recommended replacement is `score += 1`

Comment: yes you are right @vadian but score = score + 1 easy for learning purpose

Comment: No, learn the right stuff. Who is able to understand `++` will understand `+= 1`, too ;-)

Comment: okay sir you right!